# css - animation-iteration-count always infinite. desire 1 iteration

Tags: html, css

I have a `div` tag overlaying an image which is animated by growing in width and increasing in opacity.  I simply want a single iteration (which is the default, I know), but for whatever reason, it runs infinitely.  Could I get some feedback on how to accomplish a single iteration?  Thank you in advance!

markup:

```
<div class="capback">
</div>
```

css:

```
.capback {
background: #000;
opacity:0.7;
filter:alpha(opacity=40);
position: absolute;
height: 17px;
width: 465px;
top: 1px;
left: 1px;
color: #fff;
padding: 5 0 0 10px;
font-size: 12px;
 -moz-animation: fullexpand 25s ease-out;
 -moz-animation-iteration-count:1;
 -webkit-animation: fullexpand 25s ease-out;
 -webkit-animation-iteration-count:1;
 -o-animation: fullexpand 25s ease-out;
 -o-animation-iteration-count:1;
}

@-moz-keyframes fullexpand {

0%, 20%, 40%, 60%, 80%, 100% { width:0%; opacity:0; }

4%, 24%, 44%, 64%, 84% { width:0%; opacity:0.3; }

16%, 36%, 56%, 76%, 96% { width:465px; opacity:0.7; }

17%, 37%, 57%, 77%, 97% { width:465px; opacity:0.3; }

18%, 38%, 58%, 78%, 98% { width:465px; opacity:0; }

}

@-webkit-keyframes fullexpand {

0%, 20%, 40%, 60%, 80%, 100% { width:0%; opacity:0; }

4%, 24%, 44%, 64%, 84% { width:0%; opacity:0.3; }

16%, 36%, 56%, 76%, 96% { width:465px; opacity:0.7; }

17%, 37%, 57%, 77%, 97% { width:465px; opacity:0.3; }

18%, 38%, 58%, 78%, 98% { width:465px; opacity:0; } 

}

@-o-keyframes fullexpand {

0%, 20%, 40%, 60%, 80%, 100% { width:0%; opacity:0; }

4%, 24%, 44%, 64%, 84% { width:0%; opacity:0.3; }

16%, 36%, 56%, 76%, 96% { width:465px; opacity:0.7; }

17%, 37%, 57%, 77%, 97% { width:465px; opacity:0.3; }

18%, 38%, 58%, 78%, 98% { width:465px; opacity:0; } 

}
```

Comment: have you tried the non-vendor prefixed `animation-iteration-count: 1;`

Comment: hi matt!  thx for the reply.  yes, i have tried that as well.  animation just keeps on going until the duration (25s) is up

Comment: well, i seemed to have fixed my problem by removing the various percentages and going with a simple: from { width:0px; opacity:0; }/to { width:465px; opacity:.7; }

Comment: all those numbers were certainly making my head hurt a bit

Answer (score -2):

as the saying goes, "the problem usually lies between the keyboard and the chair". holds true in this case. :) i was causing my own woes with too many keyframes.

Comment: How did having too many keyframes cause this problem? How many did you have to delete to fix it?